# I have outdoor lights powered by an in-wall timer. Can I add a dimmer to work with both lights and in-wall timer?

Tags: electrical, lighting, outdoor

I installed these lights that come on with an in-wall timer switch. Here are the lights I bought:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lithonia-Lighting-6-in-3000K-New-Construction-or-Remodel-Recessed-Integrated-LED-Kit-6G1BN-LED-30K-90CRI-M6/206767185

I am really loving these lights but they are too bright. They're only 10.3w each but seem much brighter. I'd love to be able to dim them but be able to keep my in-wall timer. The other thing is, the in-wall timer controls a light on the ceiling in the entryway outdoors. Is there a way to install a dimmer that leads only to my newly installed LED recessed lights? If not I can easily connect them to another junction box with a separate in-wall timer and dimmer.

I can't remember the brand name of the in-wall timer. But if that matters I'm willing to change it out to help me keep them working on a timer.

Here is what they look like at nighttime. I feel like I'm lighting up the whole block!

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a picture showing the wires going to the existing timer and switches?

Comment: What make and model is the existing timer switch?

Comment: You might be able to replace the bulbs with a model that's half the power/brightness.  But personally I'd go with the dimmer switch as in the answers, so you can go full-bright during parties or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How hard it would be top install will depend on the exact wiring but I don't see why you couldn't wire in a dumb (non-smart) dimmer after the switch on the switched hot wire to the outdoor lights.

This depends on the wiring in the switch box but if the switched side of the timer goes to two wires, one to the indoor light and one to the outside lights, it should be doable. However, if there is only one wire going to all of the lights, you will have to pull new wiring.

Make sure to use a dumb dimmer, just a slide or rotary control, and make sure it's rated for LED loads. You'll need to make room for the dimmer, either combine other switches or add another box or something. Disconnect the wire from the load side of the timer that goes to the outside lights, leaving the indoor lights connected. In its place, connect the line side of the dimmer. Connect the load side of the dimmer to the wiring going to the outdoor lights.

Note: I have no idea if wiring a dimmer after the timer is allowed by code but I don't see any reason it would cause a safety issue.

Comment: I would expect that the "hot" feed to the existing timer switch could easily be "extended" to a second timer switch at the same location.  As you wrote, the only possible headache is if the wires go to the ceiling light and thence to the outside lights, in which case some new wires would need to be pulled.